# Passing arrays as parameters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have this function in PowerShell:

```
function Run-Process
{
    param([string]$proc_path, [string[]]$args)
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath $proc_path -ArgumentList $args -PassThru -Wait
    $exitcode = Get-ExitCode $process
    return $exitcode
}
```

And in some code elsewhere, I call it thusly:

```
$reg_exe = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe"
$reg_args = @("load", "hklm\$user", "$users_dir\$user\NTUSER.DAT")
$reg_exitcode = Run-Process -proc_path $reg_exe -args $reg_args
```

When it's called, `$proc_path` gets the value for `$reg_exe`, but `$args` is blank.

This is how array parameters are passed in Powershell, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$args` is a special (automatic) variable in PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx), don't use it for your parameter name.

`-ArgumentList` is the typical name given to this type of parameter in PowerShell and you should stick to the convention. You could give it an alias of `args` and then you could call it the way you like without conflicting with the variable:

```
function Run-Process {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string]
    $proc_path ,

    [Alias('args')]
    [string[]]
    $ArgumentList
)
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath $proc_path -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -PassThru -Wait
    $exitcode = Get-ExitCode $process
    return $exitcode
}
```

A possible alternative, that may work if you absolutely must name the parameter as `args` (untested):

```
function Run-Process
{
    param([string]$proc_path, [string[]]$args)
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath $proc_path -ArgumentList $PSBoundParameters['args'] -PassThru -Wait
    $exitcode = Get-ExitCode $process
    return $exitcode
}
```

Please don't do this though; the other workaround is better.

Comment: Ah, jeez, okay, thank you.  I didn't think of it as possibly being an automatic variable.

Comment: @supercheetah the way you worded that comment I totally read it in the voice of [Jerry Gergich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Gergich)  :)

Comment: Now you've got that in my head too.